# uploading image(multi-part data) on node js server android

Tags: android, node.js, retrofit2, image-uploading, okhttp

I am trying to upload image on  my nodejs server by android its working file on postman but it fails in android. I am using okhttp and retrofit library.
I have searched for many solutions on stack overflow and some blogs but none of them is working in my case.Retrofit call returns nothing.

My node js upload code :

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const authenticate = require('../authenticate');
const multer = require('multer');
const cors = require('./cors');
const crypto = require("crypto");



const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:(req,file,cb) => {
        cb(null,'/mnt/images');
    },

    filename : (req,file,cb) => {
        cb(null,/*file.originalname*/crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex"))
    }
});

const imageFileFilter = (req,file,cb) => {

    if(!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)){
        return cb(new Error('You can upload image files!'),false);
    }else{
        cb(null,true);
    }



};

const upload = multer({storage : storage,fileFilter:imageFileFilter});


const uploadRouter = express.Router();

uploadRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

uploadRouter.route('/')
.options(cors.corsWithOptions, (req, res) => { res.sendStatus(200) })
.get(cors.cors,authenticate.verifyUser, authenticate.verifyAdmin, (req, res, next) => {
    res.statusCode = 403;
    res.end('PUT operation not supported on /imageUpload');
})
.get(cors.corsWithOptions,authenticate.verifyUser,authenticate.verifyUser, authenticate.verifyAdmin, (req, res, next) => {
    res.statusCode = 403;
    res.end('GET operation not supported on /imageUpload');
})
.delete(cors.corsWithOptions,authenticate.verifyUser,authenticate.verifyUser, authenticate.verifyAdmin, (req, res, next) => {
    res.statusCode = 403;
    res.end('DELTE operation not supported on /imageUpload');
})
.post(cors.cors,authenticate.verifyUser,
    upload.single('imageFile'), (req, res) => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        res.json(req.file);   
});


module.exports = uploadRouter;
```

I want to upload image by key and image as value as shown in image with post.It works fine on postman.[image]

My Android Code:
Upload funcion:

```
private void upload(){

        ServiceGenerator serviceGenerator = new ServiceGenerator();
        ApiInterface apiInterface = serviceGenerator.createImageUploadService(ApiInterface.class,getContext());
        File file = new File(filePath.getPath());
        RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("imageFile", file.getName(), reqFile);
        RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "imageFile");
        Call<ResponseBody> call = apiInterface.postImage("bearer "+sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.JWT,""),body,name);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Log.i("RESPONSE","1");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("RESPONSE","0");
                Log.i("RESPONSE",t.getCause().toString());

            }
        });

    }
```

Service Generator CreateUploadService Function :

```
public <T> T createImageUploadService(Class<T> serviceClass, final Context context){

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();


        if(retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(client)
                    .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_API_URL)
                    /*.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))*/
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
```

API Interface :

```
@Multipart
    @POST("imageUpload")
    Call<ResponseBody> postImage(@Header("Authorization") String authHeader,@Part MultipartBody.Part image, @Part("name") RequestBody name);
```

Comment: can you post your android code as well as if you got any errors ?

Comment: I have updated my post please check it @kdblue

Comment: do you get any error, check your logcat .

Comment: no it didn't gave any repose, neither it fails nor it succeeds @kdblue

Comment: have tried with debug?